# Unable to Create Environment file

Tags: python, conda, virtual-environment

I am trying to install gcc using Conda. I used the "Conda install command" 
I received this error :

```
 WARNING conda.core.path_actions:verify(933): Unable to create environments file. Path not writable.
  environment location: /Users/dscott09/.conda/environments.txt
Executing transaction: failed
ERROR conda.core.link:_execute(568): An error occurred while uninstalling package 'defaults::python.app-2-py37_10'.
PermissionError(1, 'Operation not permitted')
Attempting to roll back.

Rolling back transaction: done

[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/Users/dscott09/opt/anaconda3/python.app/Contents/PkgInfo' -> '/Users/dscott09/opt/anaconda3/python.app/Contents/PkgInfo.c~'
```

I am unsure about how to solve this problem

Comment: It's saying you don't have permission, so try: sudo "Conda install command"

Comment: This is the new error after running it with sudo.                                                 Executing transaction: failed
ERROR conda.core.link:_execute(568): An error occurred while uninstalling package 'defaults::python.app-2-py37_10'.
PermissionError(1, 'Operation not permitted')
Attempting to roll back.

Rolling back transaction: done

[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/Users/dscott09/opt/anaconda3/python.app/Contents/PkgInfo' -> '/Users/dscott09/opt/anaconda3/python.app/Contents/PkgInfo.c~'